# Ionic Firebase Cloud Messaging custom sound

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using [FCM plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/) in my Ionic application to receive notifications.
I would like to give users the opportunity to disable the sound and customize it (like Whatsapp settings).
How can I do this ?
For example, to disable the sound how should I do? My app is in background or killed.

Answer (score 1):

Wonder if you've solved this...after that long.

Try this...If you have a your users' profile at your backend, then create a flag for the notification sound (i.e file name they have chosen from the app). When they customize the sound (by selecting a different, say mp3 file or selecting none), send this file name to your server and log it against their profile.

Next time your app server sends that user a notification, remember to specify the filename in the notification 'sound' field. As the notification goes to that user only, it should play the sound they chose.

However, if you are using topics, in that case the notification will be sent to a lot of users at the same time, try using the native audio plugin to play the sound the user has selected upon notification arrival. This implies you will leave the 'sound' field blank in FCM notifications from your app server.

There could be more options...